# Conditional styling depending on special css custom properties

Tags: css

[Edit 2022-10-17] It has turned out that my question below may be hard to understand. Please find here am alternative version of the question. Hopefully that's easier understandable: https://jsbin.com/bixumazugi/edit?html,output

---

Please have a look at the following demo:

https://jsbin.com/nubosuwede/1/edit?html,output

With the CSS custom properties `--is-colored` and `--is-monochrome` you can control whether the HTML output will be colorful or just in gray and black.

To switch to monochrome:

```
  --is-colored: var(--off);
  --is-monochrome: var(--on);
```

To switch to colorful:

```
  --is-colored: var(--on);
  --is-monochrome: var(--off);
```

Everything in the demo works as expected. But how can I achieve the same WITHOUT setting the default values explicitly (see body styles)?
"Colored" should still be implicitly default.

Of course the real-world use case is completely different and far more complex, but the purpose of this demo is to provide the actual problem as simple as possible in a tiny little silly demo ([Edit 2022-10-17] it's not about colors in particular, it's about setting ANY possible CSS value dependening just on CSS custom properties ... I guess a "trick" using `calc` will not work here in general).
Also please be aware that this problem does only exist if you are developing a component library (web components in my case), it is not a problem if you are developing an app, of course.

Using a CSS preprocessor or JavaScript is not the solution I am searching for.

[Edit - 2022-10-16] Please be aware that the solution must work in shadow DOM, for example in custom element slots. Any inherited custom CSS property is by design available in shadow dom, but classes aren't.

[Edit - 2022-10-17] I guess, my question above was not clear enough, sorry for that. The base problem is that I want to make styles (any styles!!! - I do not know those styles nor colors nor anything else as they are all defined by the users of my library) depending on a certain CSS custom property, let's say `--xyz`. Unfortunately, this is currently not directly possible in CSS. The next best thing is to use TWO CSS properties instead as a trick or workaround: `--xyz: inherit;` and `--not-xyz: ;` (or to invert: `--xyz: ;` and `--not-xyz: inherit;`). Now you can use for example `background-color: var(--xyz, orange) var(--not-xyz, gray);` or `text-align: var(--xyz, left) var(--not-xyz, right);` or whatever you like. This works everywhere for any style, AT LEAST if you define the default values for `--xyz` and `--not-xyz` before you use them. And I would really love to know a solution where this "predefining default values for the two css properties" is NOT necessary. TYVMIA

Comment: For the moment I am admitting defeat!  Anything that can be calculated is easy.   There is just no functionality in CSS to do the required conditionality. calc() seemed a possibility for this, but calc() I have discovered is evaluated just in time, not when assigned to a custom property, ie, the calc expression is assigned, not its value, to a custom property.  Further an invalid calc, eg, 1 / 0, invalidates the whole assignment, not the status of the assignee.  BTW you possibly should be initialising --on with 'initial'.  It is the universal invalid, whereas 'inherit' can be valid.

Comment: Please provide a more real-world example, with real used css properties (maybe `display`, `overflow`, ...) and fake shadow dom (make a fake `<shadow>`  element or something), provide all the users available options via buttons with js, explicitly saying the user cannot usa any js other that provided, of what js they can use

Comment: @Dimava @ petern069 Please find here a real-world example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/x8amcLkb/3 . Please let me know if things are still not clear. Be aware that https://jsfiddle.net/e1scbpw6/ is a valid solution for the challenge (as described in the "HTML" frame of the demo), which is an implementation of my answer somewhere below, so I actually do not know why this answer was downgraded (it's not a very nice solution and not exactly an answer to what I've asked for originally, but at least it is a solution - still hoping there are better solutions).

Comment: Thanks but sorry I do not know if I will have time in the next few days.  I will look again if I can. BTW, your solution was not DVed by me.

Comment: Please find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/41uexhjz/) another working solution for the "label layout" challenge. I think, it matches the given task 100% and does not need any "auxiliary/temporary" custom properties. But these tricks are not working in general (I guess, a proper answer for the original "color" example could not be derived from that, or at least the solution would be quite ugly)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve a simpler solution by leveraging the [CSS cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade).

In this specific case you could define your styles as follows:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.div3 {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: maroon;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.monochrome .div3 {
  color: black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      ... blah blah ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is equivalent to your demo. The idea here is that you can achieve the same level of control by simply adding the `monochrome` CSS class to *any* of the outer `div`s, while having "Colored" as the implicit default.

---

As for working with web components, I believe you could solve the problem by keeping the Shadow DOM open:

```js
const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
shadow.appendChild(document.querySelector('div1'));
```

By doing this, you should be able to manipulate the web component by using regular DOM API methods—for example, to add the `monochrome` class:

```js
document.querySelector('div1').classList.add('monochrome');
```

### Passing styles into a shadow DOM

You can achieve this by creating a `<link>` element and appending it to your shadow DOM:

```js
let link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', 'https://example.com/path/to/your/style.css');
this.shadowRoot.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: TYVM for your answer. Unfortunately my question seems to be misleading (sorry, my bad). Your solution is not working for my use case. My custom elements shall not be allowed to manipulate anything outside of themself. Otherwise the solution would be very easy: Just check via `getComputedStyle`and `getPropertValue` whether the two CSS custom properties are already defined for the root element and set them by JavaScript at root if not already defined.
I've added a link to an alterntive version of my question which is hopefully better to understand (see top comment at the question above).

Answer (score 1):

Complete rethink based on feedback.

Not sure why I did not think of the following in the first place:

- no initialisation other than setting the two state values in body
- has styling only in "target" div
- does not rely on invalid values to define/undefine variables
- only requires one mode variable instead of two
- no scripting required
- no preprocessing required

The "magic" hsl parameter values can be found at https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

This will work for properties other than color.  It will work for any property that is a length, percentage, number, etc.  I will see what can do for other properties. (I Note your "calc trick" comment above.)

```css
body {
    --monochrome: 0;
    --colored: 1;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10vw;
}

.div1 {
    /* Default mode is colored. */

    /* This is how to switch to monochrome mode: */ 
    /*
    --theme: var(--monochrome);
    */

    /* This is how to switch to colored mode: */ 
    /*
    --theme: var(--colored);
    */
}

.div3 {
    color: hsl(
            calc(180 * var(--theme, var(--colored))),
            calc(100% * var(--theme, var(--colored))),
            calc(50% * var(--theme, var(--colored)))
        );

    background: hsl(
            calc(39 * var(--theme, var(--colored))),
            calc(100% * var(--theme, var(--colored))),
            calc(50% * var(--theme, var(--colored)) + 83% * (1 - var(--theme, var(--colored))))
        );

    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: hsl(
            calc(0 * var(--theme, var(--colored))),
            calc(100% * var(--theme, var(--colored))),
            calc(50% * var(--theme, var(--colored)))
        );

    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3">
            ... blah blah ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I feel so embarressed that it seems that I have so much problems describing what I really want here, my deepest apology. The whole thing is about setting style values conditionally depending on CSS custom properties. It's not about colors, it's about ANY CSS value (for example, switching conditionally between `flex-left` and `flex-right` or whatever). I just thought using colors in the silly little demo will be easier to understand.

Comment: I've added the following line to the question above: "[Edit 2022-10-17] it's not about colors in particular, it's about setting ANY possible CSS value dependening just on CSS custom properties ... I guess a "trick" using calc will not work here in general)".
Also, I've added an additional comment at the end of the question above to make things maybe a bit clearer .. I guess nobody will read the question any longer, as it is way too long now ;-)

Comment: Nothing to feel embarrassed about. Rereading does reveal what you really want.  This is a good question (have upvoted).  The basic problem is the limited conditional functionality available in CSS. Is there any where in your library where some scratch padding can be done? Can some canonical work be down in 'body' as well as the "target" 'div' (not setting the default)?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found this topic very confusing and I don't understand why would someone use these things to build a website. Your question is really confusing because you said "no JavaScript" but you actually need to use script to access shadow root and open the mode.

Anyway, I found a way that might be what you're looking for. it uses `customElements` with `slots` and it's really boring.

**The first part:** I think it defines the element then opens shadow mode or something then attaches it to the HTML.

```
 customElements.define('div-1', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
```

**The second part:** It defines the slot name that will attach the style to its children.

```
<slot name="OrangeBg"></slot>
```

**The last part:** define the element style.

```
<style>
      ::slotted(div) { background: orange; }
      ::slotted(div) { text-align: center; }
      </style>
     `;
```

Then we add element in the HTML like this:

```
 <div-1>
    <div slot="OrangeBg">Sam</div>
  </div-1>
```

And here is a complete working example:

```html
<script>
    customElements.define('div-1', class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <slot name="OrangeBg"></slot>
          <style>
          ::slotted(div) { background: orange; }
          ::slotted(div) { text-align: center; }
          </style>
         `;
      }
    });
  
    customElements.define('div-2', class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <slot name="GrayBg"></slot>
          <style>
          ::slotted(div) { background: gray; }
          ::slotted(div) { text-align: center; }
          ::slotted(div) { color: white; }
          </style>
         `;
      }
    });
    </script>
  


  <div-1>
    <div slot="OrangeBg">Sam</div>
  </div-1>

  <div-2>
    <div slot="GrayBg">35</div>
  </div-2>

  <div-1>
    <div slot="OrangeBg">This is boring</div>
  </div-1>

  <div-2>
    <div slot="GrayBg">Let's get outta here</div>
  </div-2>
```

**The boring part** is that you need to add a custom element as a container and then the slot as the default style for the child in that container.

**The good part** is that each container can take more than one element.

I tried to make one shorter code for different styles but with no success.

For some reason, the custom element name should have a hyphen (`-`) in it to work.

### Edit

According to the link you posted in the comment:

1. You are trying to use if statement to style element but without using if statement! of course because you know no such thing in CSS.
2. You want to use variables but without redefining variables! this doesn't make sense.

So far what I understood is that you want to have a default style that is different from the default that is provided by browser. Meaning it's your custom default style. then you want to style other elements differently but if you don't, then they inherit your default style. and you want to do that without using if or predefined variables. Am I correct here?

If this is the case, then it can be done by defining a default style for all elements (*not variables*) at once or individually according to your needs. and it can be done **without** any `if statement` or `predefined variables`. check this out:

```css
* {
    /* this is the default style for all elements */
    background: lightgray;
    color: black;
    margin: 10px;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


.overwrite {
    /* this will overwrite default style */
    background: orange;
    color :blue;
}


.overwrite2 {
    /*  this will overwrite default style  */
    background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="inherit">this div will inherit default style which is lightgray background and black text</div>
 <div class="overwrite">this div will overwrite the default style</div>
 <span>this span will inherit default style</span>
 <span class="overwrite2">this span will overwrite default style</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. But unfortunately, this is not what I've meant. What I've meant is the following: https://justpaste.it/2202b

Comment: Thanks again for your help. But you still get me wrong: The question is, how to set styles conditionally based on custom properties in general (ANY styles!!!). This `someStyle: var(--xyz, someValue) var(--not-xyz, someOtherValue)` trick is AFAIK the only way to achive this for ANY CSS value. I am fine with this trick, but unfortunately it seems that you have to predefine `--xyz` and `--not-xyz` first. All I wanted to know is whether it is possible to kinda extend this trick in a way that predefining `--xyz` and `--no-xyz` is not necessary. I assume it's not possible, but who knows?

Comment: Of course, it's not possible, even the default style is defined by the user agent in each browser. good luck

Answer (score 1):

CSS simply has no 'logical function' like `selector { property: if(condition, true-action, false-action) }` which forces developers to workaround situations requiring logical switches.

You seem to have overlooked a rather convenient CSS keyword: **`unset`** ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)).

Settings *any* CSS property to `unset` means it is regarded as not having been defined, making it revert back to default behavior. Which is either:

- the keyword `inherit` when an inheritable property is set by the parent
- or the User Agent's default property value when set by the browser
- or the keyword `initial`, the HTML default for that property

In the case of CSS custom properties/variables there is also a fourth option:

- 'undefined' or simply said: *as if it does not exist at all* because there simply is no HTML default for a custom properties/variables.

In your various examples you use variables with boolean meaning:

- --on/--off
- --color/--no-color or --monochrome
- --left/--right
- --vertical/--horizontal
- etc.

In these instances the trick is to *assume* the default value (or most likely to be selected) and either *anticipate* some override or make the value `unset`. If it is not 'vertical', then we assume it is 'horizontal', if it is not 'color', then it must be 'monochrome', when not 'true', then it is 'false'...

Something like this CSS:

```css
.assumed  { --assumed : assumed-value  }
.override { --override: override-value }

.usage    { property: var(--override, var(--assumed, unset)) }
```

and the HTML:

```html
<div class="usage"         >nothing defined, will be HTML/UA default</div>
<div class="usage assumed" >will get assumed settings</div>
<div class="usage override">will get override settings</div>
```

The **snippet** shows some trickery overriding various font colors of elements. The override classes *only* define/unset color variables and do *not* set the `color` properties themselves. The `color` properties are only set in class `.parent` and the generic `div` selector.

Check it out and let me know if I need to explain more/better:

```css
/* ALL parents ASSUME 'unset' */
.parent {
    color: var( --parent-color, var(--JS-theme-color, unset));
    /* --JS-theme-color default 'unset', 'CornflowerBlue' by checkbox JS */
}

/* ALL divs ASSUME 'unset' */
div {
    color: var(--color1, var(--color2, var(--color3, var(--monochrome, unset))))
    /* when more than one color has been 'defined', first in line will be used */
}

/* Specific parent OVERRIDES */
.parent1 { /* nothing specific */ }
.parent2 { --parent-color: unset  }
.parent3 { --parent-color: Purple }

/* Specific class OVERRIDES */
.mono   { --monochrome: DimGray }
.color1 { --color1: Red   }
.color2 { --color2: Lime }
.color3 { --color3: Blue  }
.color4 { --color1: Cyan; --color2: Yellow; --color3: Magenta }
.color5 { --color1: unset; --color2: unset; --color3: unset; --monochrome: rgb(0,0,0,.7) }

/* just eye-candy */
b { padding: 0.15rem 0.5rem; color: Black; background-color: Gainsboro; border-radius: 3px }
i { color: purple }
```

```html
<label>toggle this <input type="checkbox"
        oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--JS-theme-color', (this.checked) ? 'CornflowerBlue': 'unset' );">
     to (un)set <b>.parent</b> color <b><i>--JS-theme-color</i></b>...
</label>

<h3>.parent</h3>
<div class="parent">
    <p>will get its color from:<br>
        a) either <b><i>--JS-theme-color</i></b> when set by JS<br>
        b) or <b>inherit</b> color (&lt;body&gt; not set, so highly unlikely in this demo)<br>
        c) or <b>initial</b> and as it is a color User Agents set it to 'black'<br>
        d) or color set by User Agent (best candidate without JS, Firefox anyway)</p>
</div>


<h3>.parent .parent1</h3>
<div class="parent parent1">
    <p>nothing set, will inherit the <b>.parent</b> color</p>
</div>

<h3>.parent .parent2</h3>
<div class="parent parent2">
    <p><b><i>--parent-color</i></b> set to 'unset', will inherit the <b>.parent</b> color</p>
</div>

<h3>.parent .parent3</h3>
<div class="parent parent3">
    <p><b><i>--parent-color</i></b> set to 'purple', will use this value regardless of <b><i>--JS-theme-color</i></b></p>
</div>

<h3>cascading variables</h3>
<div class="parent">
    <div>this is default, undefined color, inherits parent color</div>
    <div class="mono">only <b><i>--monochrome</i></b> defined</div>
    <div class="color1">only <b><i>--color1</i></b> defined</div>
    <div class="color2">only <b><i>--color2</i></b> defined</div>
    <div class="color3">only <b><i>--color3</i></b> defined</div>
    <div class="color4">all <b><i>--colorN</i></b> defined, overridden <b><i>--color1</i></b> is used</div>
    <div class="color5">all <b><i>--colorN</i></b> 'unset', overridden <b><i>--monochrome</i></b> is used</div>
    <div>this is default again, undefined color, also inherits parent color</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But frankly, I am not really sure whether I can derive from it a solution for the [original example](https://jsbin.com/nubosuwede/1/edit?html,output) or for the real-world challenge mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035445/conditional-styling-depending-on-special-css-custom-properties#comment130937232_10725037). Could you please do me a favor and provide a solution for at least one of those examples (FYI: Please find [here a solution for the original example](https://jsbin.com/roxeveloro/1/edit?html,output))?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this approach is okay.  The two variables '--is-colored' and '--is-monochrome' do NOT need to be set, but the initial/default colors DO need to be set.

Explanation of how it works is commented in code.

```css
body {
    --on: inherit;
    --off: ;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    --coloredText: cyan;
    --coloredBack: orange;
    --coloredBord: red;
}

.div1 {
    /* this is how to switch to monochrome mode */ 
    /*
    --is-colored: var(--off);
    --is-monochrome: var(--on);
    */

    /* this is how to switch to colored mode */ 
    /*
    --is-colored: var(--on);
    --is-monochrome: var(--off);
    */
}

.div12 {
    /*  Border color has to be handled differently because it is not an inherited property.  */
    /*  It needs to be separated from the "content" because the color needs to be set differntly.  */

    /*  The default border color.  */
    color: var(--coloredBord);  /*  This sets the currentColor, to which border-color will be set to when set to an invalid value.  */

    /*  Define the border  */
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--is-monochrome, black) var(--is-monochrome, black) var(--is-monochrome, black) var(--is-monochrome, black) var(--is-colored, var(--coloredBord));  /*  Only need five values here, because four or one is valid, but five is not.  */
    }

.div2 {
    /*  These properties are inherited when set by a child to an invalid value.  */

    /*  Default text color.  */
    color: var(--coloredText);

    /*  Default background color.  */
    background-color: var(--coloredBack);
}

.div3 {
    color: var(--is-colored, var(--coloredText)) var(--is-monochrome, black);
    background-color: var(--is-monochrome, lightgray) var(--is-colored, var(--coloredBack));

    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body style="font-size: 10vw;">
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div12">
            <div class="div2">
                <div class="div3">
                    ... blah blah ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately this is not an option in my use case. The main challenge is to make sure that everything woks as desired WITHOUT the need of (pre)defining any CSS custom properties on root or body. My question above seems to be quite misleading (sorry for that).  I've added a link to an alterntive version of my question which is hopefully better understandable (see top comment at the question above)

Answer (score -1):

[Edit] There has been some controversy regarding this answer (see comments below).
Be aware that this does match exactly as an answer to the original question. So, of course, I will not mark/accept this as an actual solution and I am still hoping somebody finds a better solution. Nevertheless, the following workaround is at least more or less close to what I've asked for (while still far away from a solution I like). There might be some special real-world use cases where this could be kinda useful.

Please find here a little demo (`--is-monochrome` is actually not needed, neither are `div1` nor `div2`): https://jsbin.com/roxeveloro/1/edit?html,output

---

Here's a solution that seems to work.
I thought it would be necessary to switch between TWO CSS custom properties, one for "colorful" and one for "not colorful".
But actually ONE CSS custom property for switching between on and off seems to be sufficient. I've called that CSS custom property `--colorful` in the following demo. To switch between "colorful" and "not colorful" just set `--colorful` to `var(--on)` or `var(--off)`.
Also remove this `--colorful: var(...)` completely to see that "colorful on" is default, if nothing is predefined.
Unfortunately we need some auxiliary custom properties to make things work (`--color-not-colorful` and `--bgcolor-not-colorful`).

» [Demo](https://jsbin.com/hupedadafe/1/edit?html,output) [Edit: If it's not clear that you really do NOT have to predefine `--colorful` to make things work, then please check [this Demo](https://jsbin.com/qitedirede/2/edit?html,output)]

Many thanks to Chris and James for [this extremely helpful article](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-custom-property-toggle-trick).

Frankly, I'm not too happy with the need of this auxiliary custom properties (`--color-not-colorful`, `--bgcolor-not-colorful`) ... if somebody knows a way to get rid of them, please let me know.

Comment: this way still uses variables, and that's against your question.

Comment: @Mad7Dragon The point is that this way you do not need to **predefine (!)** the default value for `--colorful` explicitly (Quote: "But how can I achieve the same WITHOUT setting the default values explicitly", "predefining [...] not necessary"). Maybe this demo shows it better. The default value for `--colorful` is NOT set, yet the box is colorful: https://jsbin.com/qitedirede/2/edit?html,output

Comment: But you are initialising --temp1 and --temp2, and you are using a scratch pad to do work, and while cleverly so, it is difficult for others to help when in the end most if not all of the parameters in your OP have been changed. It is your question though. Cheers.

Comment: @petern0691 Sorry, it seems I really failed in describing the problem. Like said, I also don't like those `--temp1` and `--temp2` variables, but at least it does what I've written in my very first comment for you (quote): `"The main challenge is to make sure that everything woks as desired WITHOUT the need of (pre)defining any CSS custom properties on root or body"` And this solution does not need any predefining of variable `--colorful` at all. Also I do not know where I've said that introducing local custom properties is not allowed (it's surely not preferred, but I've never forbidden that).

Comment: @petern0691 Out of interest: May I ask you what "using a scratch pad" means in this context? You've used that phrase twice. Many thanks for the clarification.

Comment: A scratchpad is a temporary or informal or unpreferred or make-do place for workings. In your case, 'box'. Nothing wrong with that. Wrongly it seems, I had got the impression such was out of scope.

Comment: In regard to the extra custom properties, again I had got the impression that such was extremely undesirable. However, if allowed, they do implement a logical 'not' for state values. The downside is that, in general, you need one for every actual property you are controlling. BTW, you may want to check out this in regard to [invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/2022/CR-css-variables-1-20220616/#defining-variables). While obviously 'inherit' works at 'root' level, it does not always have that result.

Comment: @petern0691 Thanks again for your kind help. I'll then better use `initial` instead as you've suggested. Those "local auxiliary properties" are a pain in the butt, of course. But at least for those use cases where the component developer only needs a fixed number of auxiliary properties the described pattern might be at least an option (better than nothing, yet far away from being the nice solution I hoped that would be possible).